# How to add a scope to an app engine instance?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to use start a csv file import to cloud sql from an app engine as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/instances/import).

Although this works locally, it fails when running on app engine:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/v1/projects/xxxxxx/instances/yyyyyy/import?alt=json 
returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
Details: "[{'message': 'Insufficient Permission', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions'}]">"
```

How to add the scopes to my app engine standard instance?

Comment: You might like to check IAM roles for a service account under which your App Engine is running (it might be a default app engine service account, but not necessarily) and add relevant IAM roles to allow csv import to a Cloud SQL. Pay attention to project id in case the app engine and cloud sql are in the different projects.

Comment: Check the IAM roles. It's not a scope issue, it's a permission issue.

Comment: Please [improve your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to let others understand what you did locally that worked and what you did running on app engine to understand the difference and what in this case failed. And, also, please comment if you are using GAE Standard or Flex environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be the following:

```
import google.auth
# next line had wrong scope
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
credentials, _ = google.auth.default(scopes=SCOPES)
```